# Capitalization in headlines

Tags: capitalization, headline-case

I am writing a thesis. I am aware that's a special set of capitalization [rules](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2010/02/words-to-capitalize-in-titles-and-headings.html) that applies to titles. I'm applying those in my title.

Do the same rules also apply to the titles of individual chapters and sections, though?

Comment: Titles of chapters and sections follow the same rules as titles.  Capitalize most words, except articles, short prepositions and conjunctions, and the like.  How short is a stylistic judgment, but I'd say three letters or fewer, in most cases.

Comment: When I click on your link, I get a page that says "Internet Explorer cannot display the web page."  Please check this out.

Comment: Whether to capitalize chapter, section, subsection titles, depends on the style guide. Does your institution have a thesis style manual or a template thesis? If so, follow it. If not, you might as well capitalize them.

Comment: The [Chicago Manual of Style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/717/02/) says that level 4 and level 5 subheadings should ***not*** be title case. I'd certainly expect that chapter titles would be in title case in any style guide. Sections and subsections, I'm not so sure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two levels (the title and chapters) usually follow the rules you cite.

Anything below those (levels 3, 4, etc) are really up to you.

That said, [small caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) do look good aesthetically. Level 3 in small caps only (no lowercase letters and non caps) would be pretty neat. There's an option for using them in Microsoft Word, in the Font section.